# How to add class(es) to elements generated by ngFor on hover?

Tags: css, angular, mouseover, mouseout

**Problem:** I have some html that uses *ngFor to generate a bunch of divs, all with the same class. I want to be able to add an active class to single elements. I keep running into the issue though of having that class applied to all of my elements instead of just one.

HTML:

```
  <div class="feed" infiniteScroll [infiniteScrollDistance]="2" [infiniteScrollThrottle]="50" (scrolled)="onScroll()" >
    <div class="mentions" *ngFor = 'let item of feed; let i = index;'>
    <div class="content-wrapper">
      <img src={{item.image}}>
      <div class="content-text">
        <div>{{item.name}}</div><br>
        <div>{{item.text}}</div><br>
        <div>{{item.followers}}</div><br>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="votebtn"> 
<button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="UpVote" id = u-{{item.source}} class="UpVote" (click)="vote(i, item, 'keep')">
      <mat-icon>thumb_up</mat-icon>
    </button>
<button mat-button matSuffix mat-icon-button aria-label="DownVote" id=d-{{item.source}} class=DownVote (click)="vote(i, item, 'ignore')">
    <mat-icon>thumb_down</mat-icon>
    </button>
    </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Goal:** Ultimately, I'd love to be able to do something as simple as adding `box-shadow: 1px -1px 12px 0px #c9c9c9` to the a single `mentions` element on mouseover and then remove it on mouseout. This is my most recent attempt.

```
    <div *ngFor = 'let item of feed; let i = index;' [ngClass] = 'state' (mouseover) = "state = 'mentions hover'" (mouseout) = "state = 'mentions'">
```

Again, it would add to all elements.

Comment: You probably need something like `item.state`, otherwise there is only one `state` value to be shared between all of the items

Comment: When you say `item`, are you referring to the object I'm referencing in my `*ngFor` or is this an Angular function?

Comment: The `item` variable that is created as part of your `ngFor` (i.e. `let item of feed`)

Comment: Ok, that seems pretty straightforward. Is there not a way to do this simple template syntax?

Comment: do  you need to track which item is currently "selected" or is just a visual effect?

Comment: I have code working to tracking the elements. Right now, it's just a visual effect.

Comment: Ill add an aswer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could archive this visual effect by defining a small attribute directive:

```
    @Directive({
      selector: '[ngHoverClass]'
    })
    export class NgHoverClassDirective {
       @Input(`ngHoverClass`)
       set classesToAply(v: string | string[]){
          this.classes = Array.isArray(v) ? v: v.split(' ');
       }
       private classes: string[] = [];

       constructor(private renderer: Renderer2, private element: ElementRef){}

       @HostListener('mouseover')
       onHover(){
         this.classes.forEach(c=> this.renderer.addClass(this.element.nativeElement, c));
       }

       @HostListener('mouseleave')
       onLeave(){
         this.classes.forEach(c=> this.renderer.removeClass(this.element.nativeElement, c));
       }
    }
```

After making it available for consume, you could use it in a component as follows:

```
<div *ngFor = 'let item of feed; let i = index;' ngHoverClass='hover' class="mentions">
```

Comment: Thanks! That certainly did it. I have to say though, this seems like a rather lengthy way of achieving this. There are a couple more elements in my app that share class names and will need to have something similar done to them. Is a directive the best way of going about this?

Comment: If you want to add a class, I would say this is the best approach. If you simply want to apply an extra styling, you could go the css way and use the `:hover` pseudoselector.

Answer (score 2):

Late reply. I let the object array do most of the work as this pattern is cleaner for me:

CSS

```
 li.selected {
   border-bottom: thick solid purple;
 }
 li.hover {
   border-bottom: thick dotted gray;
 }
```

Object

```
 NavigtionMenu = [
   {
     name: 'Home',
     link: 'path/to/link',
     hover: false,
     selected: false,
   },
   {
     name: 'About Us',
     link: 'path/to/link',
     hover: false,
     selected: false,
   }
 ]
```

Template

```
  <li 
     *ngFor="let item of items; let i = index"
     (mouseover)="item.hover = true"
     (mouseout)="item.hover = false"
     (click)="item.selected = true"
     [routerLink]="item.link"
     [ngClass]="{
       'selected' : link.selected === true && link.hover === false,
       'hover'    : link.hover === true
     }"
  >
   {{ item.name }}
  </li>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 <div *ngFor="let item of feed; let i = index;" [ngClass]="{'hovered': item.isHovered'}" (mouseover)="item.isHovered=true" (mouseout)="item.isHovered=false">
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! While this answer may provide a solution for the OP's needings, please, add an explanation in order to make it more understandable, not only for the OP, but also for the whole community